# intuitively Understanding meaning of a Combinatorics problem to reach solution

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, recreational-mathematics, intuition

I have been recently taking course on Combinatorics and landed on following problem, Here is the formal statement of problem:

A room contains a single bulb and $(2^{2^{10}}+2^{2^9})$ identical switches, out of these switches, exactly one switch will operate the bulb, in each attempt by a person, Any number of switches can be triggered on/off **simultaneously only**, find least number of attempts required to identify correct switch for bulb in **"all possible scenarios"**, note: All switches are turned off initially

Here is my first Attempt: I thought If they are just asking minimum possible attempts so that correct switch can be identified, Why not trigger all buttons on first attempt, and find out which button triggered the bulb on, but later realised that multiple switches can only be triggered simultaneously, from which one cannot uniquely identify which switch worked, Hence Discarded the idea, then Thought switch on all switches one by one, But its feasibility will depend on where the correct switch is, If bulb glows on first attempt, It would be minimum, if it glows for last attempt, It will be the maximum number of attempt, Hence I need to find some another mechanism to reduce number of Attempts so that they are minimum for all cases, Any ideas to Carry Forward? My intuition says it has something to do with problems where we switch half of them on and continue the cycle, But cannot grasp the logic

Also What will the minimum number even intuitively "mean" after finding the solution?

Comment: Well, whoever set the problem ought to have clarified the meaning of "minimum".  One natural definition would be "minimize the worst case".  That is, minimize the number of steps needed assuming you are as unlucky as possible.  Another would be "minimize the expected number of steps".  these definitions may, or may not, lead to the same strategy.

Comment: To start, I'd suggest guessing a strategy.  Dividing in half might be a good guess (at each stage, flip half (or as close as you can get) to the switches.  Analyze how long that takes.  Then try to sort out if that can be improved upon.

Comment: I wonder how the author had the idea for this number of switches. Just some "random" huge number or a number allowing a nice solution ?

Comment: @Peter, Well that is very much Possible, Why would author think That big of completely random number else..

Comment: "...landed on following problem...." Please, where exactly did you find this problem?

Comment: Please, Dheeraj, WHERE DID YOU FIND THIS PROBLEM?

Comment: @GerryMyerson,It was in a collection of Problems provided By my lecturer,Will ask her And Tell you the source in a short while

Answer (score 5):

For each natural $n$ let $f(n)$ be the number of steps to identify the correct switch among $n$ switches in the worst case.
I claim that $f(n)=\lceil \log_2 n\rceil$, that is $f(n)$ is the smallest nonnegative integer $k$ such that $2^k\ge n$.
We prove the claim by on induction on $n$ as follows. Clearly, $f(1)=0$. Suppose that $n\ge 2$ is a natural number and $f(k)=\lceil \log_2 k\rceil$ for all integer $k<n$.

To prove the induction hypothesis for $n$ suppose that the switches are numbered from $1$ to $n$. Trigger any $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ switches, say, from $1$ to $\lceil n/2 \rceil$. If the bulb state was switched then one of these switches operates with the bulb, but if the bulb state was not switched then one of the remaining switches operates with the bulb. In the former case it remains to check switches from $1$ to $\lceil n/2 \rceil$, whereas in the latter case it remains to check switches from $\lceil n/2 \rceil+1$ to $n$. Note that in any of these cases there remain at most $\max\{\lceil n/2 \rceil,n-\lceil n/2 \rceil\}=\lceil n/2\rceil$ switches to check. By the induction hypothesis, this can be done in at most $\lceil \log_2 \lceil n/2\rceil\rceil=\lceil \log_2 n\rceil-1$ steps.

On the other hand, suppose that at the first step we triggered exactly $k$ switches, say, from $1$ to $k$. If the bulb state was switched then one of these switches operates with the bulb, but if the bulb state was not switched then one of the remaining switches operates with the bulb. In the former case it remains to check switches from $1$ to $k$, whereas in the latter case it remains to check switches from $k$ to $n$. Thus after the first step in the worst case there can remain at least $\max\{k,n-k\}\ge \lceil n/2\rceil$ switches which can operate with the bulb so they have to be checked. Again by the induction hypothesis, they can be checked in at least $\lceil \log_2 \lceil n/2\rceil\rceil=\lceil \log_2 n\rceil-1$ steps.

Consider the following example of the proposed algorithm. Let $n=10$ and the switches are numbered from $1$ to $10$. Thus initially we have $10$ switches to check.

At the first step we trigger the switches from $1$ to $5$. Suppose that the bulb state was changed. Thus the switch operating with the bulb is one of switches $1,\dots, 5$. Thus there remains five switches to check.

At the second step we trigger the switches from $1$ to $3$. Suppose that the bulb state was not changed. Thus the switch operating with the bulb is either switch $4$ or switch $5$. Thus there remains two switches to check.

At the second step we trigger switch $4$. Suppose that the bulb state was not changed. Thus the switch operating with the bulb is switch $5$.

Comment: can you explain your method of working with an example, and clarify the induction step?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi I expanded the answer. Feel free to ask for more explanations, if needed.

Comment: sorry for late reply, could you please elaborate why making groups into half reduces the number of attempts, why can't any other methods like dividing into 1:2 or 2:3 etc. ratios would not result into minimum attempts,reframing the doubt why dividing groups near to 1:1 ratio works?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not posting this as a comment. I'm not "reputed enough" to do that. But this looks like the poisoned wine problem. I point you to [PBS infinite series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3qmN6pYhi0&ab_channel=PBSInfiniteSeries) for the solution. It's very well explained. Replace the bottles of wine with switches and the light bulk with poisoned wine, and you have a bijection from your problem to the poisoned wine problem. She discusses the solution 4:16 onward.

Comment: The question you mentioned deals with multiple wines on multiple rats with time delay ensuring no quick response is noticed, here light bulbs and switches cannot be connected to the analogy you mentioned